# Hide the sidebar on tablet and mobile without affecting layout (maintain the same width as desktop)

Tags: html, media-queries, viewport, responsive, meta

**Desktop View**
[image]

**Mobile/Tablet View**
[image]

Above shows what I want. As you can see, the desktop version has `width=1024px`, and the mobile/tablet also. The only element that changed is sidebar, which it will hide on mobile/tablet.

As usual, I use viewport meta and media queries to complete the responsive layout.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px){}
```

But it seem like different case for this time. I cannot use `initial-scale=1` because it will only shows half of the website. I have no idea what should I change for viewport meta. So that it fix nicely on tablet and mobile.
Hoping that some of you could provide me with some advice. Thanks!

```js
$(".show-hide-btn").click(function() {
  $(".menu_resp").toggleClass("menuvisible")
 });
```

```css
.floatleft{ float: left;}
.floatright{ float: right;}
.sectionpanel{width: 180px; line-height: 1em !important; background-color: #e5e5e5;}
.sectionpanel .loginsect{background-color: #c5d960; padding: 18px 14px;}
.sectionpanel .whiteborder{margin: 10px 0; border: 1px solid #f9fcfd;}
.sectionpanel .loginicon{padding-top:8px;}
.sectionpanel .logininfo{padding-left:10px;}
.sectionpanel .styleSelect select{font-size:10px; font-weight: bold; width: 152px; border-radius:5px; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #d2d0d0;background: transparent; -webkit-appearance: none;}
.sectionpanel .styleSelect { overflow: hidden; background: url("../images/icons/dropdownbtn.png") no-repeat right #fff; border-radius:5px;}

.sectionpanel .menunav{background-color:#e5e5e5;}
.sectionpanel .menunav .nav a{font-size: 12px; color:#565656; display: block; width: 155px; padding: 8px 10px 8px 15px;}
.sectionpanel .menunav .nav a:hover, .sectionpanel .menunav .nav a.active{background-color:#3f98ce; color: #fff; width: 155px; padding: 8px 10px; border-left: 5px solid #2b6a91; }


@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px){
  .header-right-btns{
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  display:block;
  z-index: 100;
 }

 .show-hide-btn{
  background:url(https://image.ibb.co/kL1Gdc/menu_respo.jpg) no-repeat left top;
  width:42px;
  height:42px;
  float:left;
  text-indent:-9999px;
 } 



 #wrapper_menu .first, #wrapper_menu .first{
  border-top:none;
 }

 #wrapper_menu .last, #wrapper_menu .last{
  border-bottom:none;
 }

 .menuhidden{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: -252px;
  background:#3d3b3c;
  z-index:10;
  transition:left ease-in-out 0.2s;
  z-index: 1000;
 }

 .menuvisible{
  left: 0;
 } 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column sectionpanel">
  <div class="header-right-btns">
    <a href="#" class="show-hide-btn"></a>
  </div>
  <div id="wrapper_menu" class="menu_resp menuhidden">
    <div class="loginsect">
      <div class="greentxt txt12">Logged in as</div>
      <div class="greentxt_bold txt12">School</div>
      <div class="whiteborder"></div>
      <div>
        <div class="floatleft logininfo">
          <div class="dartbluetxt txt10">Welcome</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div><br/>
      <div class="styleSelect">
        <select>
          <option value="">Please select premises</option>
          <option value="">Please select premises</option>
          <option value="">Please select premises</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menunav">
      <div class="nav"><a class="active" href="#"><div class="hicon">Homepage</div></a></div>
      <div class="nav"><a href="#"><div class="aicon">Main Navigation 02</div></a></div>
      <div class="nav"><a href="#"><div class="aicon">Main Navigation 03</div></a></div>
      <div class="nav"><a href="#"><div class="aicon">Main Navigation 04</div></a></div>
      <div class="nav"><a href="#"><div class="aicon">Main Navigation 05</div></a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="column secctn">
  content
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
sidebar {
  display: none;
}

main {
  width:100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px){
  main {
    width:800px;
  }

  sidebar {
    width: calc(224px);
    display: block;
  }
}
```

and you can use this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0">
```

Here, something like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/4vec4kgy/4/

Comment: I know, that was of my method for responsive layout. But now it's different case, I don't know how to hide the sidebar on tablet and mobile version. Hope you can suggest a solution instead, thanks!

Comment: Added my code. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0">` is not working on my side, only shows half of the page on mobile. Let me try the link you shared.

Comment: maybe this is even a little bit better, using position relative and left: https://fiddle.jshell.net/4vec4kgy/3/show/light/

Comment: What is the different? only added position relative?

Comment: yes and using left: instead of margin-left. Now i also added box-sizing so you can use padding in the elements without it changing width and height. https://jsfiddle.net/4vec4kgy/4/

Comment: not yet, because I need to change many. As I have finished my code.

Comment: There is an extra space below my main content. It's weird

Comment: Okay, I need to see the page to be able to help you with that. It could be the box-sizing you need to put on your main element, else I dont know.

Comment: it's ok, I think is my side issue. Because I have a code that use to make both side same line. Please approve the answer I have edited. Thank you so much! :)